# Breeze delete Projection

Tags: breeze

In my application I have an "Event". And to this Event, I can attach documents.

Now when I show a dialog of this Event, I want to list all the documents, that are related and I do this with a "select"-Projection (because I don't want the property in the document, that has the binary representation in it, which would be huge).

Now from this list, I should be able to delete a document. As I did a projection, I don't have a breeze entity for the document so I cannot call setDeleted() on the entityAspect.

How would this be done? Do I have to query the whole document just to delete it?

I do all of this in a sandboxed DataContext so just sending a command to the server to delete the document and requery is not an option - as the dialog can be cancelled.

If I do this with standard queries and navigation properties everything works fine but potentially slow if there are big images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431632/can-i-delete-an-entity-that-is-not-in-cache) answer.  Essentially, you can create an entity with the id of the entity you want deleted and set the entityaspect to 'deleted' and that should take care of it.

Comment: Pefect! Thank you :-)